# How to enable Airdrop in El Capitan on MacBook Pro early 2011 to open in Finder screen to show iOS devices

Tags: software-recommendation

I can't send or received on Airdrop because to any iOS can't show main option in Finder he say you can send to Mac only or received not including iOS software.

please help

Comment: Apple has decided that your Mac cannot use AirDrop with iOS devices.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's [support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203106):

> - Make sure that both devices have AirDrop turned on and are within 30
>     feet (9 meters) of each other.
> - If you're sending to an iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch:
>
>   - Your Mac needs to be a 2012 or newer model with OS X Yosemite or later.
>   - The iOS device must be using iOS 7 or later andhave Personal Hotspot turned off in Settings > Cellular.

Comment: oh my god I have MacBook Pro early 2011 and i road what need to have airdrop in any device 2008 or later

Comment: my Mac core I 7 hard 500 graphics 3400 ram 4 giga elcapitan os , my ipadpro iOS 9.3.3 ,I see in YouTube Mac 2008 actived airdrop by orders in terminal , in my case I have oready in my Mac airdrop but can use with other Mac not combatibale with iOS ,I want to be activated with iOS like terminal orders or any soulution thank you for help me